# change initial zoom in D3.js node graph

Tags: d3.js, zooming, force-layout

I try to change the default scale of the NodeGraph [here](http://freifunk.in-kiel.de/ffmap/nodes.html) so it fits in the screen on first load. It is written with [D3.js](http://d3js.org/). Is there an initial variable, that defines the zoom?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to change the initial gravity, which makes the zoom not needed anymore:

```
// Gravity at pageload: 
initial_gravity=0.07; // to apply a change here, enter `make` in you terminal

var force = d3.layout.force()
          .charge( function (d) {
            if (d.flags.client)
              return -30 * chargeScale

            return -100 * chargeScale
          })
          .gravity(initial_gravity)
          ....
```

afterwards you need to call `make` at the console to apply the changes

Comment: Glad it worked for you, but this wouldn't work if your graph is larger.

Answer (score 1):

You can set a suitable `transform` on the top-level `g` element, e.g. `g.attr("transform", "scale(0.8)")`.

Comment: I tried that, but didn't work, neither at the beginning of the document nor at the end